# Why 1 is not prime

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I have been told that there is some interesting mathematics to why the number 1 is not prime. Can someone explain why one is not a prime number?

Comment: By definition, a prime must have only a factor of 1 and itself. Because 1 has no other factor other than itself, it is therefore not prime.

Comment: For how long did you search before posting this question?

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat Thanks, I thought this might be a duplicate...

Answer (score 3):

Because a prime number is a number that has exactly two distinct positive divisors.

Examples:

- $2$ can be divided by $1$ and $2$
- $11$ can be divided by $1$ and $11$
- $1$ can be divided by $1$ and... $1$ so it is not prime.